# Kensington Desktop Fingerprint Key reader use with Ubuntu 23 / Linux Mint 21

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, drivers, fingerprint

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999508/is-there-a-driver-for-the-kensington-verimark-usb-fingerprint-key) may have been posed some time ago. However, it appears there were no suitable solutions at the time ...

So essentially, I would like to use a Kensington Desktop Fingerprint Key reader with Ubuntu 23 (or Linux Mint 21) for logging in and for general password entry via fingerprint detection, not unlike what may be done with Windows Hello, etc.

So, I would like to know if anybody has found a solution for using this type of USB device (or perhaps another similarly priced device) for fingerprint login and password entry via fingerprint - one that works with the latest versions of Linux Ubuntu or Mint derivatives, etc. Otherwise, is this worth pursuing, or is it better to stick to Windows if one requires this functionality?

Thanks, MM

Comment: Fingerprint reading and login are relatively standard features these days, and fprintd will allow you to do exactly that, given that Linux has a driver for your specific model of hardware. Which I'd probably

Comment: Wait you said that this has been posted already, so please link to that original question before we just spend time duplicating things that have already been written there.

Comment: Get the VID&PID of the device, google that "+linux" and you'll get your answer.

Comment: @ChanganAuto. Unfortunately I no longer have it as it was on loan temporarily. I believe the owner has sent it back for a reimbursement ... Any other way to get a driver ?